# Delete matched pairs in a file

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk

In my pursuit of finding a particularly persistent memory leak in C++ code, I've resolved to writing all allocations to a log file in the following format:

> `<alloc|free> <address> <size> <UNIQUE-ID> <file> <line number>`

This gives me, for example:

```
alloc 232108     60   405766 file1.cpp (3572)
free  232128     60   405766
alloc 232108     60   405767 file1.cpp (3572)
free  232128     60   405767
alloc 7a3620  12516   405768 file2.cpp (11435)
free  7a3640  12516   405768
alloc 2306c8    256   405769 file3.cpp (3646)
alloc 746160   6144   405770 file3.cpp (20462)
alloc 6f3528   2048   405771 file4.h (153)
alloc 6aca50    128   405772 file4.h (153)
alloc 632ec8    128   405773 file4.h (153)
alloc 732ff0    128   405774 file4.h (153)
free  746180   6144   405770
free  632ee8    128   405773
alloc 6a7610   2972   405778 this_alloc_has_no_counterpart.cpp (123)
free  6aca70    128   405772
free  733010    128   405774
free  6f3548   2048   405771
alloc 6a7610   2972   405775 file3.cpp (18043)
alloc 7a3620  12316   405776 file5.cpp (474)
alloc 631e00    256   405777 file3.cpp (18059)
free  7a3640  12316   405776
free  6a7630   2972   405775
free  631e20    256   405777
free  2306e8    256   405769
```

I'm trying to match every `alloc` to a `free` and leave just the `alloc`s without a `free` counterpart, for example, allocation number `405778`.

What I can come up with is the following shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
grep "^alloc" test.txt | while read line
do
    alloc_nr=`echo $line | awk '{ print $4 }'`  # arg4 = allocation number
    echo "Processing $alloc_nr"
    sed -i "/ ${alloc_nr}/{//d}" test.txt
done
```

As you may have guessed, this is painstakingly slow (ie. 2 loops per second) on a 25MB file with about 144000 `alloc`s, since I use `sed` in a horribly inefficient way.

It'd be very much appreciated if someone could give me a nudge in the right direction on how to achieve this without it taking three hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you want only the IDs and not the whole line:

```
$ awk '{print $4}' file | sort | uniq -u
405778
```

`awk '{print $4}'` print only the ID column.

`sort` sort the column.

`uniq -u` display only the unique IDs.

Edit:

Pipe to `grep -f - file` to match the whole line, no need to loop:

```
$ awk '{print $4}' file | sort | uniq -u | grep -f - file
alloc 6a7610   2972   405778 this_alloc_has_no_counterpart.cpp (123)
```

`grep -f` matches patterns from a file and `-` means use `stdin`.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '/^alloc/ { a[$4]=$0; }
     /^free/ { delete a[$4]; }
     END { for (i in a) {print a[i]; }' test.txt
```